# Перспективное преобразование для rowRange изображения

Tags: c++, opencv

У меня есть изображение и матрица для перспективного преобразования, как (и возможно ли это) преобразовать только `rowRange` изображения? Примерно так

```cpp
int rowStart = 10, rowEnd = 20;
cv::warpPerspetive(image.rowRange(10, 20), outImage, outImage.size());
```

К сожалению данный код работает неверно, так отсчет `y`-ков начинается не с 10, а от 0. Можно ли это исправить?

Comment: А если ROI установить?

Comment: @MBo не подскажете что это?

Comment: В С-шном интерфейсе это [cvSetImageROI](http://robocraft.ru/blog/computervision/289.html), в C++ надо смотреть

Comment: @MBo если не ошибаюсь, то это тоже самое что и применения `operator(cv::Rect)` к матрице в с++ интерфейсе. Это не работает по той же причине, что я указал в вопросе